# Keep getting warnings about low disk space on home volume

Tags: disk-usage

About once every other day I receive a warning about low disk space in /home. When I open the Disk Usage Analyzer it says my largest folder /home/chris/Music occupies the most space at 72% of 26.6GB, but it doesn't show what file(s) is causing this to occur. When I reboot my system I have enough space again. Yes /home is on a separate partition. I partitioned my system so I could switch distributions if I needed to leaving /var and /home as is. There must be some log file that builds up over time and causes this problem and then gets pruned when I reboot the system, but I can't seem to find it!

Please help. I am running Ubuntu 12 w/ Gnome3. The current work-around of rebooting is getting annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `du ~ -h | sort -h` a try. That will allow you to locate the file(s), or at least see what's taking up your space, intended or not.

Edited for the sort, that should make it much easier to read.

Comment: Still not sure what file is eating up space. That command doesn't show it. Just got another warning: Low Disk Space on "home"

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, it only shows directories the way I wrote it, my mistake. Run it like this: `du ~ -ah | sort -h > ~/Desktop/filesizes.log`. That will give you a logfile on your desktop of file sizes too (it will unfortunately still include directory sizes.) Perhaps looking at that will help you find it. The additional -a option is for "all", as in files too, not just directories.